# What is this plastic insert inside of copper pipe?

Tags: plumbing, copper

I found this plastic piece inside of a 3/4" copper pipe.  Is it a random discovery, or a leftover  from the manufacturer, or some type of water reducer?

[image]

[image: pipe]

Comment: I was thinking it was a cap to keep the pipe clean. HVAC pipe and tubing are shipped purged of air and have end caps so the pipe doesn't get moisture inside the pipe.

Comment: It looks like the remains of a [two-hole laboratory stopper](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-ufhcuzfxw9/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/13489/14663/CE-STOP02B__40674.1503517915.jpg?c=2). A giveaway is a slight taper.

Comment: This piece was found inside the pipe, so not an end cap (unless maybe for a 1/2").
This is straight sided, and plastic; I think the lab stoppers are rubber?

Comment: Inside of _what_ pipe? Context is probably important here. Was it installed somewhere or laying in your garage?

Comment: pipe was in a junk drawer of my garage, apologies I don't know its source before that

Answer (score 2):

It's a flow restrictor. They are usually installed in shower heads or other types of plumbing fixtures. It was probably left in a tool box and found it's way into the pipe or was intentionally not installed.

Comment: I don't think so.   I have never seen one like this.   But maybe it is a hillbilly version.   A shower would dribble with this thing in  the main pipe.

Comment: @DMoore  I've removed many like this from hotel showers. then put them back when I checked out.  Yes, the shower damn near dribbled.

Comment: Where exactly would this be installed that you can remove it temporarily? Just upstream of the shower head in the nipple? Why would it be in a raw copper pipe?

Comment: @isherwood   The ones I'm referring to were installed in the down pipe right before the shower head. I'd remove the shower head and then turn on the shower which would shoot out the restrictor.  The current shower heads don't have a the removable restrictors, just a small hole .